# Force users browser to popup after got an IP using DHCP

Tags: browser, dhcp, popups, captive-portal

I have seen once you connect to some networks (mostly Wi-Fi) your browser popup and sends you to a **Captive Portal** (**CP**) to authenticate in order to gain access to Internet or other network. I think this proccess is doing after **DHCP** assignment on the computer. I'd like to know what is the proccess (method/technology) used to achieve this. I mean, how the Gateway assigned in DHCP can tell (send) your computer to login in a CP? The purpose of knowing this is that I would like to new users in my networks access to a beginners blog in order to explain them how the network works, talking about services (**XMPP**, **Web pages**, **FTP**, ...) and when to find the respective client-software to start consuming services. Kind of a web for dummies. This could be very helpful. Maybe this isn't possible, but I'm using just logic: If a Captive Portal can do this, then could be a way to get this done. Maybe a standard sent on network.

So far I've seen this [*Captive Portal forcing browser to popup*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916342/how-did-a-captive-portal-force-to-open-a-browser)

PS: I'd like to point out I'm trying to get this done on **every** Operating System (**Windows**, **GNU/Linux**, **Android**, **Apple**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Captive Portals require you to have full control of the network the users are connecting through.

It is entirely up to the operating system and the users settings whether or not the captive portal page is automatically opened. All the network does is advertise it's captive portal URL to the OS and the OS decides to proceed or not. Though any further HTTP requests will only redirect to the portal.

Using the captive portal to force open a webpage that isn't actually a captive portal login page is malicious in nature and should never be exploited in the way you describe.

You can however just force the first HTTP request to open the blog you speak of. Which Is the correct way to do what you want. You should try asking that question instead.

In my opinion you'd be best to just provide the users with the option of visiting the blog to learn more about the network.

Comment: I didn't about that malicious use but I guess you are right, you should not be able to force users to enter a certain web page. I'd like to know, if possible, how to force the first HTTP request to open the blog? By the way, I'm not trying to hack anyone only dealing with very basic users with a few or none knowledge about network services and basic settings. I'm talking about people that probably never have "visited" Internet but have a computer and are trying to be in a network. Thanks anyway for your reply. @Hydranix

Comment: I wasn't at all thinking you were intentionally attempting to do something malicious. Just repurposing something that's expected to behave a certain way would be very suspicious to users. For example: Connecting to a network, windows 10 says "This network requires logging in to use the internet, click here to log in." Upon clicking the browser opens to a blog with no way to log in, or worse, something that looks like you can log in but is something else. If you use Chinese Language Windows, and don't speak much English, you may be confused.

Comment: To redirect the first HTTP request you have a few options. You can be in control of everything by using a transparent proxy server, you can go the simpler but less reliable method of controlling the DNS server assigned via DHCP and doing the redirect there, or you can meet in the middle and as long as you have control just reroute all dns query packets to your DNS server.